# .Net 7 WebAPI answers to any request with 401

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cookies, asp.net-core-webapi

Long story short:
I've created simple webapi project-.netCore 7.0- with cookies authentication.
Whenever I'm making any request from external client i'm receiving only 401
Earlier i've got problems with CORS, but luckily and hopefully managed that...

program.cs code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NawiaAPI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Services.DbContext;
using System.Globalization;

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(config.GetSection("AppSettings"));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<NawiaDbContext>(dbContextOptions =>
dbContextOptions.UseMySql(XXX,ServerVersion.AutoDetect(XXX))
.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
.EnableDetailedErrors());
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services
    .AddCors()
    .AddResponseCompression()
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(c =>
    {
        c.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        c.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        c.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
        c.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
        c.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        c.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden/";
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("UserPolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("User"));
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();
});
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
});
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
    await next.Invoke();
});
app.UseCors(options => options
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")
    .AllowCredentials()
);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.Run();
```

controller implementation:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Services;
using Services.DbContext;

namespace NawiaAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly AccountService _accountService;

        public AccountController(NawiaDbContext dbContext, IConfiguration configuration) : base(dbContext, configuration)
        {
            _accountService = new AccountService(dbContext);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("RegisterUser")]
        public IActionResult RegisterUser([FromBody] Models.Dtos.Requests.RegisterNewUserRequest entity)
        {
            return _accountService.RegisterNewUser(entity) ? Ok(true) : BadRequest(false);
        }
    }
}
```

error sample:

```
> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText:
> 'OK', url: 'https://localhost:7116/api/Account/RegisterUser', ok:
> false, …} error: null headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0),
> lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ} message: "Http failure response for
> https://localhost:7116/api/Account/RegisterUser: 401 OK" name:
> "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 401 statusText: "OK" url:
> "https://localhost:7116/api/Account/RegisterUser"
```

sample client method (Angular):

```
public Register() {
    let t = this;
    t.http.post<boolean>(t.State.webApiUrl + t.State.webApiCommandAccountRegisterUser, t.register_req).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }
    )
  };
```

Comment: "options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;" remove this and check

Comment: @Jeevanebi sadly no effect :/

Answer (score 2):

After testing in my local, I found that it was caused by the conflict between OnRedirectToLogin and AllowAnonymous.

**Test code in my side:**

```
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden/";
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                //context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                //return Task.CompletedTask;
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account/RegisterUser"))
                {
                    // Allow unauthorized users to pass through and access /Account/RegisterUser
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
                else
                {
                    // All other unauthorized users return 401
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
                
            };
           
        });
```

---

**Concepts**

[OnRedirectToLogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents?view=aspnetcore-7.0#properties) Invoked when the client needs to be redirected to the sign in url.

[Simple authorization in ASP.NET Core - AllowAnonymous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Simply puts, if unauthorized users send http request, it will be handled in OnRedirectToLogin method. It will not hit your method in controller, and get 401 code as your previous code. In my sample, it allow you access the endponit `/Account/RegisterUser`, and do nothing, then it will hit your method in controller.

Comment: what i've noticed is thayt swagger gets 200 but external angular client still 401

Comment: That’s another story, that is cors issue.

Comment: Hi @ZygmuntKołodziejczyk, I have double check the issue, the answer I post previously is correct, and I found the cors setting not works in your side because the url in `WithOrigins` is wrong. You should use `http://localhost:4200`, not `https://localhost:4200`.

Comment: @ZygmuntKołodziejczyk If the issue still not been fixed, pls let me know.

Comment: its not wroking neither with:
app.UseCors(options => options
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .WithOrigins(" http ://localhost:4200")
    .AllowCredentials()
);

or 
app.UseCors(a => a.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().SetIsOriginAllowed(b => true));

Comment: Hi @ZygmuntKołodziejczyk Could you share the sample project for me without any sensitive info, so that I can investigate the issue deeply. And if you provide the angular frontend project, pls don't forget tell me the version of npm,ng,tsc and so on, you can add it in readme.txt.

Comment: @JasonPan Please don't ask people to share sources personally. Stack Overflow questions and answers should contain all relevant code on-site.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, Thanks for the reminder, for problems that cannot be solved by this conventional approach, I usually suggest OP to create a new project or tell us how to reproduce the problem. Thanks again for your advice and have a nice day.

Comment: @JasonPan and I did use this approach... still it doesnt have any educational value for me because of this :/